# Opencv program exited with code -1073741819

Tags: c++, debugging, opencv

I am working on a video processing project using opencv and QT. Every bit of code runs perfect but when I close the GUI of my application its shows stopped working error in Windows 7:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: QtTracker3.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    510a7ebe
  Fault Module Name:    ntdll.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7600.16695
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4cc7ab44
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00052016
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.3.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

**and debugger gives:**

```
Debugging starts
HEAP[QtTracker3.exe]: 
Heap block at 0BF96368 modified at 0BF96380 past requested size of 10
HEAP[QtTracker3.exe]: 
Invalid address specified to RtlFreeHeap( 00020000, 0BF96370 )
Debugging has finished
```

I cant figure out why this happens...:-(

Comment: Can't help you without the code. So help yourself and share a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 2):

c0000005 is an access violation error, a common reason is that you might try to access something that was already de-allocated (based on the information that it happens on application exit) though a invalid pointer.

Also a common mistake with Qt is to have child widgets allocated on stack and if the parent widget is destroyed first it calls *delete* on child address (a address that isn't allocated on heap and that can cause the error too), but basically you have to debug your program to find the bug.